# Spring Roo - create web scaffolding based on json controllers?

Tags: spring, spring-roo

It would appear that the only way to build the default web scaffolding is with the standard web mvc controllers that are form based. Is is possible to automatically create views that use the mvc json controllers instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to work with JSON document serialization and desrialization in Roo projects:

- Option 1: [Built-in JSON handling managed in domain layer](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-json.html) (discussed in this section). This offers customizable FlexJson integration.
- Option 2: Spring MVC detects the Jackson library in the application classpath

  - simply use Spring's @RequestBody and @ResponseBody annotations in the controllers, or
  - take advantage of Spring's ContentNegotiatingViewResolver

Comment: Right, I've done that, I've run web mvc json setup/add/all and I've got working JSON restful controllers. But the default web interface doesn't use these, and the only way to try them out is through curl, etc. I'd like to know if there is a way to generate the default crud ui that

Comment: No, that is not possible AFAIK.